# Boundary condition on wave in Schwarzschild-Anti-deSitter spacetime at event horizon

Tags: waves, black-holes, event-horizon, boundary-conditions, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am trying to model the behaviour of a **spherical symmetric wave** near a **black hole in asymptotically Anti-de-Sitter spacetime**. The metric for such a spacetime in Eddington-Finkelstein-coordinates is

$$g \enspace = \enspace -V(r) \, dv^2 + 2 \, dv \, dr + r^2 \, d\Omega^2$$

where

$$ V(r) \enspace = \enspace 1 - \frac{2m}{r} + \frac{r^2}{\ell^2} $$

with $m$ the usual black hole parameter and $\ell$ the AdS radius. Now the equation

$$\square_g \, \phi(v,r) \enspace = \enspace 0$$

leads to

$$ \partial_v \partial_r \Phi \enspace = \enspace \frac{V'(r)}{2r} \Phi - \frac{1}{2} \partial_r \Big[ V(r) \, \partial_r \Phi \Big] $$

where I introduced a new function ("r-rescaled function") $\Phi := r \cdot \phi$.

I want to numerically solve this differential equation, however I am unable to find a boundary condition on the event horizon. The wave must be purely ingoing there, but how do I model this very ingoing condition?

---

**E D I T**:

I thought about it some more and my conclusion is that I do not need to impose those boundary conditions at the event horizon explicitly. I would be glad to know if my reasoning here is correct:

- Rewrite the metric in terms of the coordinates $(\tilde{t},r,\theta,\varphi)$ such that $\tilde{t} = v-r$. This yields

$$g \enspace = \enspace -V \, d\tilde{t}^2 + 2(1-V) \, d\tilde{t} \, dr + (2-V) \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\Omega$$

- The radial characteristics are then

$$\frac{dr}{d\tilde{t}} \enspace = \enspace -\frac{(1-V)}{(2-V)} \pm \sqrt{\frac{(1-V)^2}{(2-V)^2} + \frac{V}{2-V}}$$

- At the event horizon $r_H$ the function $V$ vanishes, i.e. $V(r_H) = 0$ and so the radial characteristics at this point are

$$\frac{dr}{d\tilde{t}} \enspace = \enspace - \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}$$

- The positiv sign corresponds to outgoing radial geodesics, the negative sign corresponds to ingoing radial geodesics. Therefore, the radial characteristic of outgoing null rays vanishes, whereas the radial characteristic of ingoing null rays is non-vanishing.
- Consequently, there is no need to impose explicity "purely ingoing" boundary conditions on the event horizon because this boundary condition is inherent to the metric itself and therefore also to the wave equation (correct?)
- The **question** finally remains, if this reasoning is alright and if this reasoning can be applied to the original Eddington-Finkelstein-coordinates without any concern. Meaning: if this reasoning is correct within the frame of the coordinates $(\tilde{t},r)$, can it be used to justify the inherent ingoing-only property at the horizon within the frame of the coordinates $(v,r)$?